# Unable to play audio while recording a video in iOS in React Native using react-native-camera

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, react-native-camera

I want to play an audio that is being played through a url using [react-native-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-player), at the same time I want to record a video so that I can capture the audio being played through the speakers of the phone in the video. I'm able to achieve this in android, but iOS is giving me a hard time.

I've already asked this on the official react-native-camera github repo, but no response yet.

**To Do First**

- [ YES ] Did you try latest release?
- [ YES ] Did you try master?
- [ YES ] Did you look for existing matching issues?

**Platforms**

No issue faced in Android

It happens only in iOS.

**Versions**

- Android: Used different versions of android, no issues faced
- iOS:
- react-native-camera: 3.44.3
- react-native: 0.64.2
- react: 17.0.1

**Description/Current Behaviour**

This happens with iOS only, it's working fine in Android. I want to play an audio while recording a video so that the audio playing on the phone's speaker can be captured through the microphone that is being used by the camera. I play the audio and as soon as I call the recordAsync() function, the audio stops and the recording starts, at first I though that it's impossible to do this in iOS due to different permission policies in iOS as compared to Android, but I was provided with an native iOS version of the app by the client that is doing the same thing, so permissions is not an issue.

**Expected Behavior**
Expected to allow the audio to keep playing while I record the video

**Steps to Reproduce**

Try playing any audio from a file or a URL using [react-native-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-player) and call recordAsync() from react-native-camera,

**Additionals**

I'm using [react-native-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-player) for playing the audio, as the audio is played through a URL, This is my RNCamera Component with props:

```js
    <RNCamera
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          captureAudio={true}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}>
          {({camera, status, recordAudioPermissionStatus}) => {
            if (showFilenameModal) {
             // show a modal to save the video file with a user entered name
            }
            if (status !== 'READY')
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    width: globalStyles.WIDTH,
                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                  }}>
                  <Text>Waiting</Text>
                </View>
              );
            return recording || processing ? (
              <IconButton
                title={'Stop'}
                icon={'stop'}
                disabled={processing}
                onPress={() => {
                  console.log('Stop Recording');
                  camera.stopRecording();
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <View
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  justifyContent: 'space-around',
                  marginBottom: 10,
                }}>
                  {/* Button to record video without playing the audio */}
                <IconButton
                  title={'Record'}
                  icon="record"
                  onPress={() => this.startRecording(camera, false)}
                />
                  {/* Button to record video while playing the audio */}
                <IconButton
                  title={'Record with Audio'}
                  icon="record"
                  showSound={true}
                  onPress={() => this.startRecording(camera)}
                /> 
              </View>
            );
          }}
        </RNCamera>
```

This is how I start the recording:

```js
startRecording = async function (camera, withAudio = true) {
    const {audioPlayer, setVideoStatus} = this.props;
    audioPlayer.stopAudio();
    setVideoStatus({
      recording: true,
      processing: false,
      uri: null,
    });

    if (withAudio) audioPlayer.playAudio();

    const video = await camera.recordAsync({
      quality: RNCamera.Constants.VideoQuality['720p'],
      // I've tried this with different flag combination i.e:
      // captureAudio: true / false,
      // keepAudioSession: true / false,
    });

    console.log(video.uri.substr(7, video.uri.length), video.codec);

    audioPlayer.stopAudio();
    setVideoStatus({
      recording: false,
      processing: true,
    });

    this.setState({
      showFilenameModal: true,
      uri: video.uri,
    });
  };
```

This is my info.plist

```xml
  <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Allow app to open camera to record video</string>
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Allow app to save videos to library</string>
  <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Allow app to use media library for audio</string>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Allow app to use location for getting current state</string>
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Allow app to use location for getting current state</string>
  <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Allow app to use microphone to record video with audio</string>
```

Just in case these are the permissions in my AndoroidManifest.xml:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The other app that I'm talking about, is not based on react native, I think it's native iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the react-native-camera community, I was able to solve this issue:

https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/3276